# SAP: minimal deployment for interacting with SharePoint through Duet Enterprise

Tags: sharepoint, netweaver

I’m ramping-up on [Duet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff972436.aspx), went through bunch of docs, so I’m ready for some fun. I have my WS 2008 x64 virtual machine ready with SharePoint 2010 on it and ready to install Duet Enterprise.

How should I proceed with the SAP side of the equation? As I’m not familiar with it, is there a download + guide for getting the minimal required SAP installation up & running to try Duet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Duet, but you can get a trial edition of SAP from [here](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/nw-downloads). It's called developer edition and it's a stripped down version of SAP system mainly designed for developers to play around. It has the ABAP stack (ABAP is a SAP owned programming language) and a dbms (I cannot remember which one). I don't know what are the minimum requirements to work with Duet, like any extra modules, so you'll have to find this out.

Bear in mind that it's not a simple installation. It's very demanding in hard drive space and it will work better on Windows XP, without anything else installed, as it tends to conflict (especially with other dbms'). Maybe a virtual machine is a solution.

Comment: Thanks! The modules that Duet uses from SAP are, mainly: NetWeaver, SAP Workflow engine. (I could get away without CCMS tools for now.) I hope they are included in the package above. Thanks again.

Comment: NetWeaver is practically the name of the whole basic SAP system on which other modules are added on. As for the workflow engine, I'm not very sure that its included.